# Property not storing between pages:

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a .vb file on a site which stores a few dozen properties that are used on various pages of the site. I'm new to the company and the only web-developer, but I didn't make the site myself. I'm here to try and update it.

I've added two properties to the file, one works and the other doesn't but I can't see why?

(Out Of Stock works, New Total doesn't)

**First:**

```
Property OutOfStockItems() As Integer
    Get
        Return intOutOfStockItems
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        intOutOfStockItems = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Set Here** (Cart.aspx) - This property is set based on the amount of items in the cart with the Out of Stock boolean as 'true'.

```
Protected Sub btnCheckout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheckout.Click
    c.intOutOfStockItems = ooscount
    c.decNewTotal = Decimal.Parse(total)
    Response.Redirect("billing-details.aspx")
    'txtVoucher.Text = "New Total: " + c.decNewTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

**Used Here** (Billing-Details.aspx) - One page later in the cart process

```
'Check if customer has ordered out of stock items
        If c.intOutOfStockItems >= 1 Then
            pnlOutOfStockBlurb.Visible = True
        Else
            pnlOutOfStockBlurb.Visible = False
        End If
```

**Second:**

```
Property NewTotal() As Decimal
    Get
        Return decNewTotal
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        decNewTotal = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Set here** (Cart.aspx)  - This decimal value can be used anywhere on the cart page.

```
    Protected Sub percentageDiscount()

    Dim invert As Integer = 100 - Voucher.DiscountAmount
    Dim percent As Decimal = invert / 100
    total = Decimal.Parse(grandTotalInt)

    If Voucher.AppliesTo = "Cart Total" Then
        If total > Voucher.Amount Then
            total = total * percent
        End If

    End If

    c.decNewTotal = Decimal.Parse(total)
    txtVoucher.Text = c.decNewTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

**Does nothing here** (Payment-details.aspx) - This is two steps later in the cart process (Cart -> Billing-Details -> Payment-Details), always displays as 0.

```
lblSavings.Text = c.decNewTotal.ToString()
```

This line here on the cart page displays the correct number to a textbox, but that number doesn't go to the new page at all.

```
txtVoucher.Text = c.decNewTotal.ToString()
```

***Edit***

```
Imports DataAccessLayer
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net

Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class payment_details
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim c As User

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Comment: Can you confirm the class in which these Properties are declared?

Comment: Properties are in a separete .vb file (User.vb) which is declared at the top of every page, it's used for anything to do with a customer's session.

Dim c as User

Comment: Can you show the code that declares it at the top of the Payment-details.aspx page?

Comment: Ok. So on every page you declare a new instance of User. That means your values are going to be empty again. You need to find a way for the properties to persist across your various pages. This could be done with a Base Page property to hold the User, alternatively you could store it in Session. Do you need an example of this?

Comment: There's a check for Session in the page_load of every page as well. The system in place works very well for about 25 other properties across the site (it's a mess, but it's close to 40 pages). It just seems to be something to do with my latest property (New Total) which is screwy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80118/discussion-between-darren-s-and-chris-hinton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are accessing a class declared locally as c.

To get the values to persist across pages, you are likely storing that class in a Base Page or in Session.

If you are storing it and retrieving it from Session, make sure after you set it's Properties you are saving it back into Session.

```
Session("Customer") = c
```

Also you don't seem to be using the class Properties to Set or Get the values.

```
Protected Sub btnCheckout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheckout.Click
    c.intOutOfStockItems = ooscount
    c.decNewTotal = Decimal.Parse(total)
    Response.Redirect("billing-details.aspx")
    'txtVoucher.Text = "New Total: " + c.decNewTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

Should be like this;

```
Protected Sub btnCheckout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheckout.Click
    OutOfStockItems = ooscount
    NewTotal = Decimal.Parse(total)
    Response.Redirect("billing-details.aspx")
    'txtVoucher.Text = "New Total: " + NewTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

When you set the value via the Property, the property itself will set the value of the local variables **intOutOfStockItems** and **decNewTotal**

Comment: I've changed it, but the NewTotal property is still having no effect on the payment-details page... lblsavings.text still shows as 0.

Comment: @ChrisHinton It looks odd to me that all of your Subs have access to c.intOutOfStockItems and c.decNewTotal, c wasn't passed in a parameter to the Sub so I can only assume it is already declared as a Property, can you paste in the code that shows us where this c object declared.

Answer (score 0):

I may be off here - but in the example that works, you are setting the property. In the second, you are setting the item that you keep the value of the property in (decNewTotal v. NewTotal). This may be trivial, but if you already have a property, you might as well set/use it.

As I was typing a new answer was given about the get/set. Also, make sure that it isn't any of the above values (invert, percent,  total) that are truncating your value to zero, ie. check what value c.decNewTotal when set by:

> c.decNewTotal = Decimal.Parse(total)

Good luck.